# Use Java8 Stream on JDBCTemplate Results from HIVE

Tags: hive, java-stream, jdbctemplate

I am using jdbcTemplate to query hive then writing the results to a .csv file. I basically just generate a list of objects then steam the list to write each record to the file. 
I will like to stream the results as they coming back from hive and write it to the file instead of wait to get the whole thing then processing it. Can anyone pointing me to the right direction? Thanks!

```
private List<Avs> queryAvsData(String asSql) {
    List<Avs> llistAvs = new ArrayList<Avs>();
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = hiveJdbcTemplate.queryForList(asSql);
    Iterator<Map<String, Object>> it = rows.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map<String, Object> row = it.next();
        Avs laAvs = Avs.builder()
                .make((String) row.get("make"))
                .model((String) row.get("model"))
                .build();
        llistAvs.add(laAvs);
    }
    return llistAvs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's a built-in solution, but you *can* do it. Basically, you wrap the existing functionality in an iterator, and use a spliterator to turn it into a stream. [Here's a blog post on the subject:](https://blog.apnic.net/2015/08/05/using-the-java-8-stream-api-with-springs-jdbctemplate/)

> The code implements Spring’s ResultSetExtractor interface, which is a Single Abstract Method (SAM) interface, allowing the use of a lambda expression to implement it.
>
> The implementation wraps the SQL ResultSet in an iterator, constructs a stream using the Spliterators and StreamSupport utility classes, and applies that to a Function taking a stream of row sets and returning a generic result.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to stream values from `JdbcTemplate`. The following example is a service based on Spring Boot 2.4.8.
As, I run into problems (connection leak) using `queryForStream` then I will put a demo code here just to know that stream must be closed after usage.

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SingleColumnRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DataCleaningService {
    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void doSomeStreaming() {
        String nativeQuery = "SELECT string_value FROM my_table WHERE column = :valueToFiler";
        Map<String, Object> queryParameters = Map.of("valueToFiler", "my value");
        SingleColumnRowMapper<String> stringRowMapper = SingleColumnRowMapper.newInstance(String.class);
        try (Stream<String> stringValueStream = jdbcTemplate.queryForStream(nativeQuery, queryParameters, stringRowMapper)) {
            stringValueStream.forEach(stringValue -> {
                // do the needed action with the value
                //..
                System.out.printf("My cool value: %s", stringValue);
            });
        }
    }

}
```